Spectral mapping theorem for unbounded self-adjoint operators
Is there actually a Spectral mapping theorem for unbounded self-adjoint operators as there is one for bounded operators? I suppose yes, but I can't find good references. Just for the spectral theorem.
I am looking for a result that allows me to interchange the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of the unbounded operator $A$ with a continuous function $f$ on $\sigma(A)$ like:
$$ \sigma(f(A)) = f(\sigma(A)).$$
Could anyone recommend a good reference?
Thanks in advance!

The most general spectral mapping theorem (for spectral measures) is theorem 13.27 in Rudins Functional Analysis:
There it is proven that for any spectral measure $E$ on a set $\Omega$ and measurable $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ it is true that $\sigma ( \int f dE)$ is the essential range of $f$ with respect to $E$.
The statement in the OP can not be true in general, because $f (\sigma (A))$ is not necessarily closed (but $\sigma(f(A))$ always is) as leoli1 pointed out in the comments.
However the statement $\sigma(f(A)) = \overline{ f (\sigma (A))}$ is true.
It can be proven using the aforementioned theorem from Rudin:

Proposition: Let $A$ be an unbounded self-adjoint (or just normal) operator on a Hilbert space and
let $E$ be the spectral measure associated to $A$.
Let $f: \sigma (A) \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function.
The essential range of $f$ with respect to $E$ is defined by
$$
\operatorname{essRan}(f) := \{ y \in  \mathbb{C} : \forall U \subset{\mathbb{C}} \text{ open neighborhood of } y: E(f^{-1} (U) ) \neq 0 \}.
$$
Then
$$
\sigma (f(A)) = \operatorname{essRan}(f) =\overline{\operatorname{ran}(f)},
$$
where $\operatorname{ran}(f)$ is the range of $f$, that is to say $\operatorname{ran}(f)=f(\sigma (A))$.

Proof:
The first equality is just theorem 13.27 in Rudin applied to $E$ and $f$. To show the second equality:
Let $z \in \overline{\operatorname{ran}(f)}$ and $U$ an open neighborhood of $z$. Then there exists $y \in \operatorname{ran}(f)$ with $y \in U$ by definition of the closure. Therefore $V:= f^{-1}(U)$ is a non-empty open subset of $\sigma (A)$ by the continuity of $f$ and hence $E(V) \neq 0$ (proven below).
This shows that $z \in \operatorname{essRan}(f)$.
Now if $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{\operatorname{ran}(f)}$, then there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $z$ with $U \subset \mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{\operatorname{ran}(f)}$, since the set is open. Therefore $f^{-1}(U) = \varnothing$ and so $E(f^{-1}(U))= E(\varnothing) = 0$. Showing that $z \notin \operatorname{essRan}(f)$.
Proof that $E(V) \neq 0$:
Assume that $E(V) =0$, let $\lambda \in V$ (exists because $V$ is non-empty) and define
$$
\begin{align}
g : \sigma (A) &\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\\
t &\mapsto \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\lambda -t } \ \text{if} \ t \notin V, \\
0, \quad \ \text{else}. \end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Then $g$ is bounded and hence $g(A)$ is a bounded linear operator.
By the rules of the functional calculus (Thm. 13.24 and the Remark after in Rudin)
$$
g(A)  (\lambda I - A) \subset (\lambda I - A) g(A) = ((t \mapsto \lambda -t) \cdot g)(A) \\
= \chi_{ \sigma (A) \setminus V} (A) = E (\sigma(A)) - E(V) = E (\sigma(A)) =I,
$$
where $\chi$ is the characteristic function. But this means that $\lambda I - A$ is invertible, which is a contradiction to the fact that $\lambda \in \sigma (A)$. Therefore $E(V) = 0$ must be false.

The essential range is not the same as the range, but it should be the closure of the range. We need this because we are dealing with unbounded operators, so $\sigma(A)$ need not be compact and so $f(\sigma(A))$ need not be closed for continuous $f$

@leoli1 thanks for the correction i have updated the proof to include all the details.
